# .animate() and going back to original state

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a bit new to jQuery, and trying to learn it. I am animating an element after its parent is clicked, but I also want the element to go back to its original state after a set time period. I did try `setTimeout` but I may be using it wrong, so it didn't work. Can someone explain how to do this?

```
var span = $('span');

$('button').click(function(){


    span.animate({

      left: '200' }, 500, 'linear',  function() {

      });
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that like this.  You save the original value for left and use the `delay()` method to chain multiple animations with a time delay between them:

```
var span = $('span');
// insert span into your document somehow
// set absolute positioning on it
$('button').click(function(){
    var origLeft = span.css("left");
    span.animate({left: '200' }, 500, 'linear').delay(2000).animate({left: origLeft}, 500, 'linear');
});
```

Working demonstration here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/zB5NL/

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfectly clear what you mean but you could save the initial value of the CSS property and then animate "back" in the callback. And you should append the span to the DOM before you can animate it.
 Something like:

```
var span = $('span');
$('body').append(span);
$('button').click(function() {
    var left = span.css('left');
    span.animate({
        left: '200'
    }, 500, 'linear', function() {
        //animate back to starting position
        span.animate({
        left: left
    }, 500, 'linear');
    });
});
```